# WordPress theme navbar stop Working when resizing the browser screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying a WP theme but when I'm resizing the browser windows size then the mobile menu is not working but in the same small windows after refreshing the browser page the menu is working.

As I don't know much about coding so if anyone can have a look and help me :)

Here's the link of that demo theme: https://demo.wptravelengine.com/travel-booking/

Someone helped me with this code.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {

   jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
     jQuery("#toggle-button").click(function() {
       jQuery(".site-header .right").css("right","0");
})
jQuery(".btn-close-menu").click(function() {
    jQuery(".site-header .right").css("right","-540px");
}) })
});
```

But when I am using this code, it is not showing the close icon button and search form holder when opening it after resizing the web browser screen.

see the pic here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Il3UT1Wehcg0nAyCfW2smVSbdpCwPS0b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I know this isn't necessarily the answer you're looking for but this behavior is very common due to the fact that users do not usually resize their browsers while visiting a website. As long as the theme works as intended after refreshing the page I wouldn't worry about this too much unless, say, a client explicitly demands this fixed for whatever reason. Obviously, rotating a smartphone or tablet shouldn't break the navigation though.

Comment: Thanks, Chris for your valuable reply. I understand that but my dad wants it to work so that's why :)

Answer (score 0):

If the above code was working, I added some my thoughts. 
It will be work.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {

   jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
     jQuery("#toggle-button").click(function() {

       jQuery(".site-header .right").addClass("open");
    })
    jQuery(".btn-close-menu").click(function() {
        jQuery(".site-header .right").removeClass("open");
    }) })
});
```

Comment: It is still not showing the close button and the search form. See the screenshot, please.

Comment: Could you give me the site URL ? I fixed it under your demo site.

Comment: Hey, I am currently developing the site on XAMPP. It's not online yet. Everything is working fine just the search form holder and the close button is not appearing after resizing the browser.

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.site-header .right .btn-close-menu { z-index: 9999999!important; } } plz add it to css file